# Insert value into a table when strings match conditions from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in a PostgreSQL database. Table2 has an FK from table1's PK.  I want to search table1 for specific strings, and if I find matches I want to update a column in table2 with a string.

```
Table1 
+----+------+------+------+
| PK | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | A    | x    | x    |
|  2 | x    | x    | x    |
|  3 | x    | A    | x    |
|  4 | x    | x    | x    |
|  5 | x    | x    | A    |
+----+------+------+------+

Table2
+----+-----------------+
| FK | matching_column |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | string          |
|  2 |                 |
|  3 | string          |
|  4 |                 |
|  5 | string          |
+----+-----------------+
```

So where table1 contains '%A%'
update table2 with 'string'

I'm not sure where to start on this one. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Read about [`UPDATE … FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery:

```
UPDATE table2
   SET matching_column = 'string'
 WHERE fk = (SELECT pk
               FROM table1
              WHERE "Col1" LIKE '%A%'
                 OR "Col2" LIKE '%A%'
                 OR "Col3" LIKE '%A%');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `update ... set ... from` syntax. If I followed you correctly, you want:

```
update table2 t2
set t2.matching_column = 'string'
from table 1 t1
where
    t1.pk = t2.fk
    and 'A' in (t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3)
```

This phrases as: if the `fk` of `table2` exists in `table1` and one of the 3 columns contains `(col1, col2, col3)` contains `'A'`, then set column `matching_column` in the corresponding record in `table2` to `'string'`.